# SItecore Marketing automation is not working for OOB email opened event

Tags: xdb, xconnect, marketing-automation

I have created a `Marketing Automation` campaign and selected `Send Email` action for contacts. Post this action, I am adding a listener for 3 minutes where I have added a rule "`Where contact opened any email`" or "`where contact opened email 'email'`" . The email is getting sent but the listener is not getting passed.

When I checked the `Experience Profile` of the contact, I am seeing the `Email opened` event getting triggered. PFB screenshot, [image]

But for some reason in the Marketing Automation flow, this is not working. When I checked the logs in AutomationEngine folder, I am getting below errors,

```
2022-07-03 13:37:27.944 -04:00 [Error] Failed to submit context.
Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> Polly.CircuitBreaker.BrokenCircuitException: The circuit is now open and is not allowing calls. ---> Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.ConnectionTimeoutException: A task was canceled. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<SendAsync>d__51.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<SendAsync>d__51.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.CircuitBreaker.CircuitBreakerEngine.<ImplementationAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Policy`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.CollectionBatchWebApiClient.<ExecuteBatch>d__11.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Polly.CircuitBreaker.CircuitStateController`1.OnActionPreExecute()
   at Polly.CircuitBreaker.CircuitBreakerEngine.<ImplementationAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Policy`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.CollectionBatchWebApiClient.<ExecuteBatch>d__11.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.CollectionBatchWebApiClient.<ExecuteBatch>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Operations.HttpOperationInvoker.<Execute>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbContext.<ExecuteBatchAsyncInternal>d__108.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbContext.<ExecuteBatchAsyncInternal>d__108.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbContext.<SubmitAsync>d__75.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Diagnostics.XdbContextCountersDecorator.<SubmitAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Loading.AsyncXdbLoader.<LoadContactsAndInteractionsAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
2022-07-03 13:37:27.949 -04:00 [Error] Failed to load contact '{0}'.
Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> Polly.CircuitBreaker.BrokenCircuitException: The circuit is now open and is not allowing calls. ---> Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.ConnectionTimeoutException: A task was canceled. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<SendAsync>d__51.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<SendAsync>d__51.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.CircuitBreaker.CircuitBreakerEngine.<ImplementationAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Policy`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.CollectionBatchWebApiClient.<ExecuteBatch>d__11.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Polly.CircuitBreaker.CircuitStateController`1.OnActionPreExecute()
   at Polly.CircuitBreaker.CircuitBreakerEngine.<ImplementationAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Policy`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.CollectionBatchWebApiClient.<ExecuteBatch>d__11.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.CollectionBatchWebApiClient.<ExecuteBatch>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Operations.HttpOperationInvoker.<Execute>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbContext.<ExecuteBatchAsyncInternal>d__108.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbContext.<ExecuteBatchAsyncInternal>d__108.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbContext.<ExecuteAsync>d__72.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.XdbContext.<GetAsync>d__64`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Diagnostics.XdbReadOnlyContextCountersDecorator.<GetAsync>d__32`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Loading.AsyncXdbLoader.<LoadContactsAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
```

When I am creating a `Segmented List` using the same rule, it is working perfectly fine. But it is not working in MA. I have checked `Predicate XML` in Automation engine folders and it looks good. Any suggestions ?

Thanks,
Rashmi

Comment: It seems that MA can`t connect to xConnect. In the connectionstrings.config file, in the folder xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Config The thumbnail in xconnect.collection.certificate does not match the xconnect client certificate; or the url in the app setting xconnect.collection does not match your xconnect url.

Comment: @x3mxray - Thanks for the response. I have checked the Thumbprint and Url too. All looks good. Other rules like "Gender matches" etc. are working fine in MA flow but There are email related rules causing issue.

Comment: I think that error is not related to your problem (because of xConnect connection works with gender rule). Some users already faced similar error in MA, and solution was to Disable TLS 1.3 on IIS.

Comment: @x3mxray - I checked and TLS 1.3 is not present on IIS. Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reached out to Sitecore support and looks like it is a bug with `Sitecore 10.2 OOB`. Email campaign Model was not registered properly in Automation engine. After adding below configuration to `<Models>` node of `"sc.XConnect.Client.xml"`, The issue was fixed.

```
<EmailCollectionModel>
<TypeName>Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Model.XConnect.EmailCollectionModel, Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Model</TypeName>
<PropertyName>Model</PropertyName>
</EmailCollectionModel>
```

The xml file is present here - **\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\config\sitecore\XConnect**

Thanks,
Rashmi